# Reconhecer um JSONObject ou JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

Estou desenvolvendo um app que consome dados de um WebService, que por vez podem devolver um ou mais registros. Até o momento sempre recebia um JSONArray, fazia a "conversão" dele:

```
JSONArray arrayDados = new JSONArray(dados);
```

Porém, quando eu recebo apenas um objeto nessa resposta, como devo tratar para não dar erro na "conversão", já que ele não é um JSONArray e sim um JSONObject.

PS.: Hoje eu resolvi do modo arcaico (pra entregar), fiz um try/except like a gohorse para poder dar continuidade, e na exceção, eu chamo o tratamento para JSONObject:

```
JSONObject objectDados = new JSONObject(dados).
```

Comment: Você não pode na hora de mandar o JSON já ser uma lista, mesmo que seja com 1 objeto apenas?

Comment: Funciona até, mas, só trocaria a gambiarra de lugar...
Andei vendo em alguns lugares, e algumas pessoas diziam: "teste com o try/catch" e outras diziam pra usar o "instaceof".

Comment: Tenho o mesmo aqui, só que na hora de gerar o Json ele é um array já com 0 elemento. Ai não tenho problemas pra fazer isso, porque já sei que  todo objeto recebido para conversão é um list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlos,

Você pode identificar se é um objeto ou array usando o JSONToken:

```
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
  // Você tem um objeto
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
  // Você tem um array
```

Porém, se você tem acesso ao WebService, é mais fácil retornar seus dados em um array, mesmo que com um único objeto, desta forma você pode usar a mesma lógica.

Usando o JsonTokener você terá que fazer duas lógicas, uma para tratar um objeto único e outro pra tratar uma lista de objetos, se você sempre retornar um array, o tratamento é o mesmo para um item ou para N itens.

O que eu faria, pois considero inclusive uma boa prática, enviar um Objeto Json com alguns parâmetros de controle e um array com os dados:

```
{  
   "status":"true",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"1"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4"
      }
   ]
}
```

E no Android você pode sempre esperar um Objeto Json contendo um statuse os dados sempre estarão num array:

```
JSONObject objServerResponse = new JSONObject(strJsonServer); // <---- Sua String recebida
String status= objServerResponse.getString("status");
JSONArray arrayDados = objServerResponse.getJSONArray("dados");
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayDados.length(); i++) {
                      try {

                          JSONObject objItem= arrayDados.getJSONObject(i);
                          // faça algo com o objeto que você pegou


                       }catch(JSONException e){
                          return "Erro ao converter o JSON " + e;
                       }
   }
```

Desta forma você pode implementar a mesma lógica, desde que mantenha o mesmo padrão de JSON, e por cima você pode ter outras variáveis no JSON que te poupem trabalho, por exemplo, caso não exista nenhum objeto no banco, retornar falso no status e interromper a lógica, retornar uma mensagem do servidor, etc..